# Network Resillience Options

Tags: hardware, dhcp

I didn't see an obvious post, I want to put up the question here before rolling my own solution / help others.

I have a rpi at a remote location that suffers frequent power outages triggering a race-condition that the rpi is usually online before the WAN gateway - leaving the rpi online, but without a network.

So the options to resolve this failure mode:

- Use a static ip on the rpi and WAN gateway
- Call "Smart Hands" to reboot the rpi
- Add a script to check that the network is physically up, then restart dhcpcd
- Configure dhcpcd to auto-retry (not sure this is in buster release)

While option #4 is most ideal, I am not concerned why this is not the default-shipped behaviour. Is there some downside that I'm missing? I'm not a huge fan of setting a static ip in case the WAN Gateway changes, which could further isolate the device until I'm able to get out to the location.

Comment: This is normal operation for the Pi, so you need to explain what you are doing. `systemd` has an option to wait for network before running a service and `raspi-config` has an option to wait for network.

Comment: thanks. No customization on the network setup - I'll check and report-back..

Comment: Okay - I hadn't bothered to look at:
https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config

I agree this solves the at-boot issue..

Comment: Dhcpcd should be doing this automatically -- it has notifications for when an interface goes up, down, etc. -- so there must be some reason that is not happening in this case.

Comment: If you experience frequent but short power outages, I recommend an extra like the [Pi juice](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-standard), that will act as UPS. Or better yet, set up an UPS at the remote location to cover the whole installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `raspi-config` there is a *System Options* **Network at Boot** option which delays boot until there is a network.